# Можно ли создать класс-обертку за слежением за окном windows?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, qt5

В общем мне надо создать класс-обертку, для слежения за положением любого окна (ну допустим по его HWND) в Windows. Я знаю в Qt есть класс QWindow, но там вроде есть сигналы, но привязать его к любому Windows окну, по HWND пожалуй нельзя.

Answer (score 4):

Или я не понял вопрос, или...

Есть такая функция API [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms633519%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), которая по `HWND` возвращает его координаты. Ее, конечно, можно обернуть в что-то вроде

```
class PosWindow
{
    HWND h;
    public:
    PosWindow(HWMD h):h(h){}

    LONG left() const
    {
        RECT r;
        if (GetWindowRect(h,&r)) return r.left;
        throw ...
    }
    ...
```

Но зачем огород городить?...

Или я неверно понял вопрос?

Comment: Спс. Ну как просто хотелось бы чтобы при перемещении окна параметры обновлялись и брать уже готовые не вызывая каждый раз функции, может так быстрее хз.

Comment: У меня ощущение, что постоянное обновление будет куда дороже, чем один вызов функции именно тогда, когда это необходимо...